# ruby on rails Importmap::Packager::HTTPError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

i want to use javascript npm in rails 7 app but import map throw error every time.
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/importmap-rails-1.1.5/lib/importmap/packager.rb:80:in `handle_failure_response': Unexpected response code (403) (Importmap::Packager::HTTPError)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w99QS.png)

and my tzinfo-data has error when i what to rails new App, and dont install importmap in new app generate i install it manually

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue, after testing it was found that importmap does not have permissions.

Please execute `chmod 744 bin/importmap` command to see.